# How to allocate memory for an array of strings of 10 characters

Tags: c

I have the following variable called lines and want to allocate memory for 10 instances of the variable.

```
char (*lines)[30];

lines = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char) * 30);
```

It does not work, I don't know if the issue is with the declaration or allocation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "10 instances of the variable"?

Comment: I need to allocate 10 strings of each 30 characters long.

Comment: So, put that in your question. You should also clarify if you want C or C++ answers. Your code looks like C, but you had tagged the question C++.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I meant only c language.

Comment: "*It does not work*" what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 lines = malloc(10*sizeof(*lines));
```

will do the trick.   In fact, the general technique of

```
 pointer = malloc(number_needed * sizeof(*pointer));
```

is a general way to reduce errors when using `malloc()`, since `sizeof(*pointer)` always gives the size of the elements needed.

However, that is a C technique (just as your question is really C, not C++).

In C++, you would be better off in C++ doing

```
 std::string lines[10];
```

or (if you want the option to dynamically change the number of lines at run time)

```
 std::vector<std::string> lines(10);
```

`std::string` and `std::vector` are declared in the standard headers `<string>` and `<vector>` respectively.

Comment: There is a difference between 30 strings and string capacity 30.

Comment: Indeed.   The C++ samples I've given result in 30 strings, not strings of capacity 30 (since `std::string` can resize itself).  Will fix to be 10.

Comment: How can I add values to each item.

Comment: strcpy(lines[0], "123456789012345678901234567890");

Comment: I was looking for 10 strings of capacity 30 characters. any help?

Comment: The point is, if you're using `std::string` you do not really need to worry about the string capacity - a `std::string` will resize itself as needed.  However, to answer your question, use `std::string`'s fill constructor.  For example, `std::vector<std::string> lines(10, std::string(30, ' '))` will create a vector containing 10 strings, each of which contains 30 space characters.  `std::string` cannot be directly passed to `strcpy()` either - it supports other operations do do such things, which are normally considered preferable to anyone except a C programmer who wants to use `strcpy()`.

Comment: @user2340048: "*`strcpy(lines[0], "123456789012345678901234567890");`*" this would overflow the target. Remember that C-"string"s are `0`-terminated `char` arrays. So `char s[30]` allows you to store 29 `char`s only.

Answer (score 2):

`char (*lines)[30]` declares `lines` as pointer to array of 30 char. If you want to allocate 10 elements of such array, the allocation should be done as follows:

`char (*lines)[30] = malloc( 10 * sizeof( *lines ) );`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to allocate 10 arrarys, whose length is 30 characters long for each, with only one malloc() function call. You must be intend to use the variable 'lines' as an index for the allocated memory, since the allocated memory is actually an array of 10*30=300 chracters.

What you have to check is the type cast of the malloc() function. The variable 'line' is a pointer to 30 chracters, whereas your type casting before malloc() is poting a char.

```
lines = malloc(10 * sizeof(char) * 30);
```

Comment: Much easier to say `sizeof(*lines)` and avoid hard-wiring the number 30, which might get out of sync with the definition of `lines`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have a lot to learn how to explain more efficiently.